# AlertDialog not showing items with Material Component Theme

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, material-components-android, material-components

How do I show items inside AlertDialog.Only Alert Dialog is shown without any items I am trying this below code but this doesn't seem to be working:

```
CharSequence[] choices = {"Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3"};

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.title))
.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.Ok), null)
                            .setNeutralButton(context.getString(R.string.Cancel), null)
.setSingleChoiceItems(choices, 1, null);

AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

I am using material components styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry guys actually I was running another dialog activity!!

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same problem. Then after trying a lot of solutions I came to know that remove `setMessage()` worked for me in MaterialAlertDialogBuilder

Comment: same problem with setMessage()

Answer (score 1):

```
  String[] listItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.shopping_item);

  AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            mBuilder.setTitle("Choose an item");
            mBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(listItems, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    mResult.setText(listItems[i]);
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
            mDialog.show();



 <string-array name="shopping_item">
    <item>Onion</item>
    <item>Sausage</item>
    <item>Milk</item>
    <item>Garlic</item>
    <item>Beef</item>
    <item>Veggies</item>
    <item>Olive</item>
    <item>Cheese</item>
    <item>Tuna</item>
    <item>Mushrooms</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: @AndroidDev Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Material Component Theme you could use the [**`MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md).

```
      CharSequence[] choices = {"Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3"};
      new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this)
          .setTitle("Single Choice Dialog")
          .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
          .setNeutralButton("Cancel", null)
          .setSingleChoiceItems(choices, 1, null)
          .show();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe because you are using `charsequence` change it to `string[]`

```
String[] choices = {"Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3"};
```

Comment: @android-dev can you post a screenshot